# css style .well width wrap around text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple textbox within a `.well` and want to style the width of the `.well` class to be not much bigger than the text I put in.

Is there an easy way to achieve this with CSS?

Comment: post your existing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
.well{display: inline-block;}
```

Example.

```css
.well{
  display: inline-block;
  background: gold;
}
.textbox{
  background: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="well">
  well
  <div class="textbox">textbox</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use max-width property in the style for the box and

```
.well-class{width:auto; max-width:200px;}
```

for the class, This will work.

Comment: Need to put above property with the textbox class

Comment: Tell me if more help needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think better use `Textarea`, then text automatically wrap the textarea field's width.

```
<textarea rows="5"></textarea>
```

Comment: @steven, your issue is solved with my answer then please click 'accept this answer' button :)